# Loki endpoint on Kubernetes returning a 404 status

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, grafana, grafana-loki

I am trying to pull logs from the Loki server directly for parsing - however, I am having trouble accessing the Loki server using the internal cluster IP. The service for the Loki server is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: loki
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: pulumi
    chart: loki-2.1.1
    heritage: Helm
    release: loki
  name: loki
  namespace: monitoring
  resourceVersion: "15144"
spec:
  clusterIP: LOKI_IP
  clusterIPs:
  - LOKI_IP
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http-metrics
    port: 3100
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http-metrics
  selector:
    app: loki
    release: loki
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

In order to test wether the service is up and running I run:

```
wget http://LOKI_IP:3100/loki/api/v1/status/buildinfo
```

However, I get a 404 error when running it:

```
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

I have tried testing it with the service name as well and got the same results. How can I access the loki endpoint from within my pods using the service IP and port?

I am accessing it through a k8s pod using the service IP address and to test it - I run inside the pod's shell:
wget `http://loki.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:3100/loki/api/v1/status/buildinfo`

Comment: from where you are trying to hit the IP ? from local computer to k8s cluster ? where is your cluster running ?

Comment: assuming you are trying to access it from another pod, are you in the same namespace ?

if not  try, `wget http://loki.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:3100/loki/api/v1/status/buildinfo`

Comment: @Kaishkugashia I have tried that method as well and I got the same results

Comment: @HarshManvar I have updated the question for your reference

Comment: what you mean by `accessing it through a k8s cluster using the pod IP address` ? just run `kubectl port-forward svc/loki 3100:3100 -n monitoring` and open browser and type URL : `localhost:3100` or `localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/status/buildinfo` check if that works or not.

Comment: I still get a 404 after port forwarding and updated the question for more  explanation. @HarshManvar

Comment: try `http://loki.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:3100/ready` instead and see if that works

Comment: I also recommend sharing more about how you're deploying loki so others may be able to help. E.g. share the helm values / helm template you're using etc.

Comment: @ashes999, can you try without defining your ip (LOKI_IP) for `specs.clusterIP`